# How to automatically scroll down when RecyclerView is renewed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, chat, smooth-scrolling

I have a RecyclerView, and I'm trying to get it to scroll down every time a new message pops up. I struggle to do so. I'm not even sure If I am doing it in the right place. I'm doing it inside of my RecyclerView adapter inside of the function `onBindViewHolder()`. Here is the code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.apply {
        tvTitle.text = messages[position].title //here I am setting the title - the name of the person who wrote the message
        tvMessage.text = messages[position].message //here I am setting the message - the message written by the person
        rvTodos.smoothScrollToPosition(itemCount - 1) //and here, at last, I am setting the my recyclerview(rvTodos) to smoothly scrool down to the itemCount position (the size of the messages array)
   }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return messages.size
}
```

Comment: Try  recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(listSize); when your recyclerview is renewed

Comment: you mean messages.size? if so, it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, where are you executing this?

Comment: in a recycler view adapter, inside of onBindViewHolder

Comment: No, you need to execute this in your Activity or ViewModel, wherever you are updating the contents of the ArrayList that is eventually feeding your recyclerview

Comment: Okay, I'll try that

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! since this isn't an actual answer, I'll answer my own question with what you said and credit you!

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was simply not updating the recyclerview in the correct place. I was attempting to update it inside of the recyclerview adapter when it actually needs to be updated inside of my activity or viewmodel - where I update the contents of my messagesArrayList! Solved by: Tendai (in the comments of the question)